# Apply filter based on select list - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-filter

Array 1: Categories -> Category_Name, Category_Id

Array 2: Items -> Item_name ... etc , Category_Belonging_Id

I need to filter shown items based on selected category.

```
<div class="list>
    <select>
       <option ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-model="category_type">
          {{category.Category_Name}}
       </option>
    </select>

<a ng-repeat="item in items | filter: // What should I put here?" href="#">

...

</a>

</div>
```

Comment: can you share this issue on jfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should use `ng-option` instead of `ng-repeat` like

```
<select ng-model="category_type" ng-options="category.Category_Name for category in categories"></select>
```

and use `filter` like

```
filter:{Category_Belonging_Id:category_type.Category_Id }
```

[see demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaynishad/8s8n762v/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have:

```
Catergory = {
id 
name
}
```

and

```
MeatType{
    id
    catergoryId
    name
    }
```

You can do something like

```
<a ng-repeat="item in meatTypes | filter: {categoryId : catergory_type.id}" href="#">
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the MeatTypes refers to Items.. I've edited my question. You say category_type.id but I assume you mean category_type.Category_Id. Right ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a ng-repeat="item in meatTypes | filter: {Category_Belonging_Id:category_type.Category_Id }"   href="#">
```